# SFTP ChRoot result in broken pipe

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, openssh, chroot

I have a website that I want to add some restricted access to a sub-folder. For this, I've decided to use CHROOT with SFTP (I mostly followed this link : http://shapeshed.com/chroot_sftp_users_on_ubuntu_intrepid/)

For now, I've created a user (sio2104) and a group (magento).After following the guide, my folder list look like this :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       27 2012-02-01 14:23 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       21 2012-02-01 14:24 info.php
drwx------ 15 root root     4096 2012-02-25 00:31 magento
```

As you can see, i've chown root:root the folder magento I wanted to jail-in the user and ...everything else by the way. Also in the magento folder, I chown sio2104:magento everything so they can access what they want. Finally, I've added this to sshd_config file :

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group magento
        ChrootDirectory /usr/share/nginx/www/magento
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        PasswordAuthentication yes

#UsePAM yes
```

And the result is...well, I can enter my login, password and it's all finished with a "broken pipe" error.

```
$ sftp sio2104@10.20.0.50
[....some debug....]
sio2104@10.20.0.50's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.20.0.50 ([10.20.0.50]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Write failed: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

Verbose mode gives nothing to help. Anyone have an idea of what I've done wrong? If I try to login with ssh or sftp with my personnal user, everything works fine.

Comment: What does the OpenSSH server log say?

Comment: What version of OpenSSH is the server running?

Comment: Typical issue: *all* parent directories must be owned by root and only the user may have write permissions. See also output of `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.

The chroot-dir must be set to owner root and group root.
(chown root:root chroot-dir)

Comment: It is. The chroot-dir is magento. And as it said in the tutorial, I've remove right to everyone....maybe that's where I made an error?

Comment: If it were a permissions error, you would not be able to get past authentication.  You are getting past authentication, so something else is preventing your session from starting.  What is your `Match` block from `sshd_config`?

Answer (score 7):

Try having your default directory different to chroot directory.

I have set /home/ftpman as my default directory.

```
vi /etc/passwd

..
ftpman:x:1001:1002::/home/ftpman:/bin/bash
```

and

```
ls -la /home

...
drwxr-xr-x  5 ftpman sftponly 4096 Jun 25 11:56 ftpman
```

Then I have chroot directory set to /. And it works for me

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

...
Match Group sftponly
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory /
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: There's practically no chroot in your answer.

Comment: My problem was ```ChrootDirectory /FULL_DIRECTORY_HERE``` instead ```ChrootDirectory / ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but as far as I understand the chroot process, SSHd will fork as your user first, then tries to chroot. This will obviously fail as the directory can't be accessed being `sio2104` on the system.

Try loosening up the filesystem permission on the `magento` folder (`chmod o+rx`).